# How to register Entry Points for network python package installs?

Tags: python, setuptools, software-distribution

I have a user environment where most python packages are installed on a network share and are made available via the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  Python itself is still installed locally.  Some of those packages need to register setuptools [Entry Points](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#entry-points).  Normally, this would happen by running the `setup.py` file for the package, but because these are installed to a network location, that `setup.py` is never run with the local installation of python.

Is there a way to register Entry Points without installing a package in the local python installation?

An example of an entrypoint that registers a callback for a plugin system

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points={
        'xx_plugin': ['value = package.module:func'],
    }
)
```

Comment: What kind of entry point?  Is it for registering plugins, `console_scripts`, `gui_scripts` or something else?  A proof of concept code snippet for how the entry point is used would be helpful.

Comment: @LexScarisbrick  All of the above.  I've added an example of an entry point that installs a callback for a plugin.  Is there a way to tell setuptools to install the entrypoints without installing the python package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Run `setup.py`

The `console_scripts` and `gui_scripts` entry points create standalone scripts that wrap a callable object.  The [`coverage`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) package is a good example of this. It has an entry point to create a wrapper script for convenience. Example `setup.py` snippet to create a console script:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'script_name = package.module:function'
        ]
    }
)
```

It's possible to only install the scripts to a specified directory via `setup.py`. An existing script will not be overwritten unless the `--force` argument is passed.

```
python setup.py install_scripts --install-dir /some/alternate/location
```

For a plugin, the entry point is stored as metadata in an egg that's typically installed with the package. Example plugin entry point:

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'group_name': [
            'plugin_name = package.module:function'
        ]
    }
)
```

It's possible to only install the metadata of a package (including any entry points) to a specified directory via `setup.py`.

```
python setup.py egg_info --egg-base $PYTHONPATH
```

## Roll your own

If `setup.py` can't be run to write the egg metadata, it's totally possible to roll your own, as it's only a text file in a directory.  Example metadata based on the above entry point:

```
# $PYTHONPATH/entry_points.egg-info/entry_points.txt
[group_name]
plugin_name = package.module:function
```

To test entry point lookup:

```
import pkg_resources as pkg

for entry_point in pkg.iter_entry_points('group_name'):
    plugin_name = entry_point.name
    plugin_module_name = entry_point.module_name
    plugin_callable = entry_point.load()
    # do something with plugin
```