# Python package discovery for entry points subgroups

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, setuptools, distutils

I've been practicing to [pack python libs with `setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) and I'm aware of [`entry_point` keyword usage](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) and also about [using package metadata](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-package-metadata) to [collect entry_points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37285457/2989289) for a given group.

My question is, do `pkg_resources`, `importlib`, `pkgutil` or any other known package provide a way for **discover subgroups** of a given entry point group? I mean, find all groups starting with a certain prefix:

```
>>> import pkg
>>> pkg.find_subgroups('entry.point.group')
entry.point.group.first
entry.point.group.other
entry.point.group.one.more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `entry_points` method from `importlib.metadata` package.
The `importlib.metadata` package was introduced in python 3.8. For lower versions of python you can install the backported package `importlib_metadata`

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (3, 8):
    from importlib_metadata import entry_points
else:
    from importlib.metadata import entry_points

discovered_plugins = entry_points()
grps = set(for grp,eps in discovered_plugins.items())
for grp in grps: 
    if grp.startswith('entry.point.group'):
        print(grp)
```