# How to dynamically add entire plugin packages to main package namespace via entry points?

Tags: python, plugins, namespaces, entry-point

Consider this package that is intended for a main package `my_package`:

```
plugin-a-repo
├── setup.py
└── plugin_a
     ├── __init__.py 
     └── code.py
```

I made it discoverable by adding this to `setup()` in `setup.py`:

```
entry_points={'my_package.plugins':['plugin_a = plugin_a']}
```

Now I can load it from anywhere using

```
from importlib_metadata import entry_points
discovered_plugins = entry_points(group='my_package.plugins')
loaded_plugin_a = discovered_plugins["plugin_a "].load()
```

**Question:** How can I add this and other plugin packages to the main packages namespace, so that users, after importing `my_package`, can discover and access all available plugins through the main package's namespace:

```
dir(main_pkg.plugins) 
> ...
> plugin_a
```

or

```
from main_pkg.plugins.plugin_a.code import stuff
```

I get the dynamic loading part (e.g. shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37285457/5238559), but I fail to see how I can add the loaded packages to the main package's namespace.